# search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doc_type' - while connecting remote elasticsearch

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, flask

I am trying to connect remote elasticsearch which version is

```
"version" : {
    "number" : "7.0.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "e4efcb5",
    "build_date" : "2019-04-29T12:56:03.145736Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.7.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  }
```

and in my local python elastic version is also same

`elasticsearch==7.0.1`

when I am doing any query, I am getting this error-

```
TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doc_type'
```

my python code is -

```
res = es.search(index=brand_index, doc_type=brand, body={
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            }})
```

Comment: Can you show your Python code that runs the search? There's an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/930) that reports this.

Comment: Please go through the issue I linked to.

Comment: I have added my python code also

Comment: @Val I am not using helpers.scan

Comment: Well, underneath it's the same plumbing, so same issue